# Find <tr> using its selector text and then get its title

Tags: jquery, tags

I just can't seem to get the syntax right for this.  Ultimately I'm trying to get the tooltip to display a table's sub-group tr title text, for whichever cell is hovered inside that subgroup.

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr data-cb-name="group1" title="A_Heading">
    <td>A_Intro</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin1</td>
    <td>manage1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin2</td>
    <td>manage2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-cb-name="group1" title="B_Heading">
    <td>B_Intro</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin3</td>
    <td>manage3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin4</td>
    <td>manage4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

var Col1 = "";
var Col2_3 = "";

  $.each($('tr'), function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-cb-name"))
    {
      Col1 = $(this).attr('title')
      console.log('Col1 =', Col1);
    } else

    {
      Col2_3 = $(this).closest("[data-cb-name ='group1']").attr("title", "title").text();
      console.log('Col2_3 =', Col2_3);
    }

  })

})
```

The objective is that whenever hovering over 'admin1', 'admin2','manage1' or 'manage2', I want the tooltip to display 'A_Heading'.  And whenever hovering over 'admin3', 'admin4','manage3' or 'manage4', I want the tooltip to display 'B_Heading'.  To do this I need to travel upwards in the table to find the closest tr that contains:

```
data-cb-name="group1"
```

... as that is common to all sub-group headers. The title text however is dynamic, and this is what I want to assign to the tooltip. The line:

```
Col2_3 = $(this).closest("[data-cb-name ='group1']").attr("title", "title").text();
```

... is the line giving me all the trouble. I've tried all combinations of closest, find, attribute and text that I can think of, but I can't get a result for 'Col2_3' in the console.
Can anyone put me out of my misery!

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  Seems logical but I just get 'undefined' in the chrome console.

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.closest` isn't going to work for your case, you want the previous sibling with the data attrbute: `data-cb-name`, `.closest` will look through ancestors (parent and upward) not siblings. Please see documentation on `.closest()` - (https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. You are setting the attribute `title` to the word "title" and `.text()` isn't necessary.

Change to the following using `.prevAll` to get the closest tr sibling with the data attribute and grab it's attribute title:

```js
$(function() {
    var Col1 = "";
    var Col2_3 = "";

      $.each($('tr'), function() {
        if ($(this).attr("data-cb-name")){
          Col1 = $(this).attr('title')
          console.log('Col1 =', Col1);
        } else {
          Col2_3 = $(this).prevAll("[data-cb-name='group1']").attr("title");
          console.log('Col2_3 =', Col2_3);
        }

      });

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr data-cb-name="group1" title="A_Heading">
    <td>A_Intro</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin1</td>
    <td>manage1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin2</td>
    <td>manage2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-cb-name="group1" title="B_Heading">
    <td>B_Intro</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin3</td>
    <td>manage3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>admin4</td>
    <td>manage4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. Yes, .closest was certainly wrong.  Your help much appreciated.

Comment: @Silverburch Glad to help. Have a good day! :)